# Accessing and querying excel sheet in similar way as database is accessed

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vb.net, excel

I just wanted to know if we can access excel spreadsheet in the same way like we access MySQL database over the internet. Actually I am trying to make an application that will run on multiple computers simultaneously and all the computers will be able to edit or retrieve data on the excel spreadsheet located on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Windows ODBC to create a Data Source that can be accessed like a rational DB. ODBC has a special driver for Excel files, among other formats (Access, CSV, Plain text, ...).

You can access ODBC Data Source Administrator from the Administrative Tools in Windows Control Panel.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this is a bad idea. You can definitely access information in an excel spreadsheet from vb.net, but it can be somewhat buggy, and small issues turn into big issues. You're better off to use SQL Server Express. If you decide to continue to use Excel, you may want to stick with VBA. It's built into excel and although it still may cause issues, it will probably be a lot cleaner.